# How to remove an entire iframe tag (google maps) from a WYSIWYG content?

Tags: php, html, regex, tags, strip-tags

I want to remove from server-side (php) the iframe tag of an embedded Google Map.

It's a symfony 1.4 project and I want to remove this from the action before serving the html to the response.

The tag looks something like this. At first glance it seems a task to be solved using regex.

```
<p>
<iframe width="425" height="350" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?hl=en&amp;mpa=0&amp;ctz=-60&amp;mpf=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;msa=0&amp;t=m&amp;vpsrc=6&amp;msid=207463975658802969656.0004b1369c88b98702faa&amp;ll=44.705998,8.068085&amp;spn=0.085403,0.145912&amp;z=12&amp;iwloc=0004b136a142301cefe0c&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
<br><small>View <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?hl=en&amp;mpa=0&amp;ctz=-60&amp;mpf=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;msa=0&amp;t=m&amp;vpsrc=6&amp;msid=207463975658802969656.0004b1369c88b98702faa&amp;ll=44.705998,8.068085&amp;spn=0.085403,0.145912&amp;z=12&amp;iwloc=0004b136a142301cefe0c&amp;source=embed">Test</a>
in a larger map</small>
</p>
```

Is there any other solution or a valid regex which could do this?

I would like only the `<iframe>` tag to be removed if possible

Comment: You should use Javascript and client side iteration. If you want to do it server side you have to reload the page

Comment: I want to do this before I serve the html response.

Comment: You mean like [this](http://codepad.org/YVjjxOGt) ?

Comment: @MihaiIorga it works without the <p> tags. I will edit my post: it seems I don't need to remove the whole <p> tag. Thank you. Post as answer for accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
echo preg_replace("#<p>(.*)<iframe(.*?)maps.google.com(.*?)</iframe>(.*)</p>#is", '', $string);
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/YVjjxOGt)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/<iframe.*?\/iframe>/i','', $this->product->description);
```